# Regular expression didn't matched the actual service, getting pattern mismatched error

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Main service : "`/xxxxx/yyyyy/200426792?limit=100&offset=0`"

I tried with regex : "`/xxxxx/yyyyy/\\d+/[?]limit[=]100&offset[=]0`"

Could you please help for this.

Comment: Your regex wants a `/` after the number, that's why it dosn't match.

Comment: Escape the forward slashes `\\/`, remove the backslash before `\d`, and remove the forward slash before `[?]`?

Comment: You need to escape / with \/ and don't need to unnecessarily escape = char. Your regex and compactly written as \/x{5}\/y{5}\/\d+\?limit=100&offset=0 and also remove extra / after \d+

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your forward slashes `/` to indicate the the `/` is part of the string and not part of the regular expression. To escape your forward slashes add a backslash before them. Also, your regex is currently expecting a `/` after your number sequence specified by `\d+/`...

Fixing this all this will give you:

`\/xxxxx\/yyyyy\/\d+[?]limit[=]100&offset[=]0`

Which will successfully match:

`/xxxxx/yyyyy/200426792?limit=100&offset=0`

See example below:

```js
const str = "/xxxxx/yyyyy/200426792?limit=100&offset=0";
const regex = /\/xxxxx\/yyyyy\/\d+[?]limit[=]100&offset[=]0/g;

console.log(regex.test(str)); // true indicates that it matches
```